# Request wordpress page and specify the page template

Tags: wordpress

I have a website running Wordpress with a specific, custom theme and I would like to use some of the pages as an iframe within a different website.

The problem I am having is that I don't want to show the menu, header and footer, I want to use a different font and have the page load as quick as possible.

The best way to do this is to apply a different, bare page template to the page I want to embed as an iframe. However this will also affect the page when displayed on the website. There are plugins that will enable the content to be shown as json. This gets close to what I want to do but since it's an iframe I'd prefer to have some basic styling in there.

Is it possible to do the request for the iframe in a way a different page template is applied?

I've tried reading up about this but due to the sheer amount of articles explaining how the page template hierarchy works I've not been able to find anything explaining how to make the client influence this.

**tl;dr** can I do some sort of ?apply_template='page-bare.php' to enforce a different page template?

Comment: Might I suggest using AJAX to just grab the markup from the other page (the bit you want) and return it in your other site? That way no styling comes across anyway... You could do this pretty easily with [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: We actually do want the styling to come along, it will be embedded documentation in a webapplication I want to update without having to roll out a new version of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you: [Load post with a different template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/load-post-with-a-different-template)

The way is:

- Register new query variable
- Redirect to a different template, when that query var is set
- Create that template in the way you like it

[`get_template_part`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) might also come in handy here.

Comment: That should do it! I'll just have to see if this also applies to pages, not just to posts.